# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 in thinkpad e14 gen 3(amd) DOS operating system

Tags: boot, 20.04, thinkpad, bios, ms-dos

I have lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 3 (AMD) which has Free-Dos OS and when I am installing Ubuntu 20.04Lts using bootable pendrive and after installing it and when I restart . I also reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 too but nothing changed . It shows only lenovo logo and nothing else .After 3-4 times I restart and after that i searched Google then it says that select HDD . I did not find HDD / ptt . I did not know to solve that problem . Please help

Comment: My PC doesn't boot after installing Ubuntu 20.04lts . It has different bios( icons and menu )  than other older bios . So I didn't know how to change bios setting.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/thinkpad_p43s_p53s_ubuntu_installation_whitepaper_v1.0.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4tdWc7r3zAhX54jgGHaU_DNMQFnoECBsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3wOBoUUY2RMf369bo63OyR

Comment: I follow all the steps but after restart step nothing happens and the screen (lenovo logo) appears and nothing more . That's the place where I stuck

Comment: i myself got this answer , that is i firstly install ubuntu 16.04 which is compatible for this pc , i causes a lot of error so update 16.04 to 18.04 then from 18.04 to 20.04  and all issues is solved now . its the amd problem . thanks

Answer (score -3):

I faced this issue and after multiple iterations found a working solution.
Firstly make sure to use the Ubuntu ISO for the version 20.04.3
To create the bootable usb, avoid using Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator.
The solution works only when Balena Etcher is used to burn the usb.

During installation , do not connect to the internet. You can update and upgrade once the installation is complete.

Following the above steps, Ubuntu 20.04.3 will be installed on Thinkpad E14 Gen3

Comment: This is wrong in each paragraph: (1) SDC does the exact same thing that Balena Etcher does with the EXACT same result; (2) Installing updates during or post Ubuntu installation also gives the EXACT same result; (3) the point release doesn't matter - after installing updates the end point is EXACTLY the same - the current one is 20.04.4.